# Pagination on table isn't adding ?offset

Tags: php, html, pagination

Got a table i'm working on. Trying to get it to grab all the users from the `$json` variable, then add `?offset=25`

However, when I click it and the URL is changed, the actual data inside doesn't move on.

```
<?PHP
    $offset = 0;
//Stream Follow Json
    $json  = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/greatbritishbg/follows?limit=25&offset". $offset));
    $i = 0;
//check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not

//this part goes after the checking of the $_GET var
    $num= 25;
// Creating an object
    $json->follows;
        if($num>0)
        {
            echo "<table border=2>";
            echo "<tr><td>Username</td><td>Follow Date</td></tr>";
            foreach($json->follows as $follow) { 
                $i++;
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><a href='" . $follow->user->_links->self . "'>" . $follow->user->name . " (".$i. ")</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $follow->user->created_at . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }//for
            echo"</table>";
        }
//now this is the link..
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?limit=25&offset='.($offset+25).'">Next</a>';

$prev = $offset - 25;

//only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
if ($prev >= 0)
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?limit=25&offset='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
?>
```

If I add `?limit=25&offset=50` to https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/greatbritishbg/follows then it will display the next set of users in the database.

but if I add `?limit=25&offset=50` to my url on my site, it doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
limit=25". $offset
```

Becomes

```
limit=250
```

You need

```
limit=25&offset=". $offset
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work... and how it becomes 250... also, when I manually type in the limit and offset it doesn't change the data values.

Comment: `$offset` is set to `0`, so what you're saying is join `limit=25` and `$offset` which becomes `limit=250`. In my example above, you are adding `&offset=` so it then concatenates the `$offset` variable in making it `&offset=0`. Make sense?

Comment: Ahh I get it now :) I updated my code above, it's still not updating the data. I assume it's because my NEXT and PREVIOUS are $_Server not changing the JSON. How would I go about changing the JSON url?